# emacs 24 c++ auto-indentation broken

Tags: emacs, indentation

I'm running Emacs 24 on Ubuntu 10.04, coding c++ in the default c++ environment. Periodically after a while coding, my indentation engine seems to break -- pressing "tab" to indent places places any line at the beginning of the line. Selecting the entire buffer result in the entire buffer being un-indented. This problem effects all buffers, current or later opened. So far the only way I have found to repair it is the (highly inconvenient) step of restarting emacs. Is there another way to reboot my indentation engine? Attempting to load different indentation styles does not fix the problem.

Comment: I have noticed this happens when I `#include` specific headers (particularly template-heavy headers; commenting out the offending `#include` or restarting Emacs seems to fix the issue). I'm leaving this comment here to help people try to isolate this issue so it can be properly fixed, as Emacs 24.3 still has issues. If I find something conclusive I'll update.

Comment: Always not fixed ? Its really annoying...

Answer (score 4):

Have you read this thread?

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2012-09/msg00216.html

It sounds like you can fix your problem by updating cc-mode.

Answer (score 3):

I see the same with 24.3 but I found that closing and re-opening the affected buffer also solves the issue.

Comment: same here ... just upgraded to emacs 24.3.1 (xubuntu 14.04) and I'm finding that occasionally the indentation engine gets it completely wrong.  Didn't notice this on earlier emacs.  Closing the file and then re-opening is a work-around.

Answer (score 2):

This is a recurring issue on my system (Emacs 24.3 x86_64 Red Hat Linux) and could possibly be a bug introduced in Emacs 24 judging from the [link posted by event_jr](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2012-09/msg00216.html).
I encounter the issue fairly often and usually resolve it by reloading whatever buffer I'm working in:

`M-x revert-buffer RET yes RET`

This way you don't have to close neither buffer nor Emacs.

Comment: Closing and opening the file works, simply reverting the buffer does not unfortunately (24.3.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

Comment: Same for me revert-buffer is not enough :/

Answer (score 0):

I found unbalanced preprocessor directives (#ifdef etc) can throw it into this sort of behaviour